# Unexpectedly lost speaker output. Headphone output works fine

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones, speakers, mint

Yesterday when I opened my laptop I noticed that I no longer had sound from the built-in speakers.  I carefully checked settings in Sound Preferences, and then dropped to shell and looked in alsamixer.  Nothing is showing muted or 0/no volume.  Everything is on and set to max volume.   The profile is Analog Stereo Duplex, the default.

Sound works fine when using headphones.

I'm runnning out of ideas and even updated my kernel to 3.8.8 in hopes that would shake this loose.  No dice there (kernel works nice btw).

Here are my current specs:

```
RELEASE=14
CODENAME=nadia
EDITION="MATE 64-bit"
DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 14 Nadia"
DESKTOP=MATE
TOOLKIT=GTK
```

Alsamixer screengrab:
[image]

I don't want to load up my question with irrelevant conf files - if I need to post more here please indicate in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem about a week ago. I don't know whether we have the same issue, but I solved it with

```
sudo alsamixer
```

and by setting the "speakers" volume to 100. Then I turned on the volume at:

Settings > Sound > Sound Effects > Alert volume

Comment: Alert volume was a 0, turned it all the way to the right.  Still no change in original problem.

Comment: I edited my answer, because it wasn't the only thing I did to fix the problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did you notice the screenshot in my OP?  alsamixer speaker is set to 100 already.  Running out of ideas.