# No sound by speaker in ubuntu 12.04, only by headphones (re installing, updating and in liveUSB without sound)

Tags: 12.04, sound, live-usb, alsa, speakers

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and the speakers don't work. Before I had 13.04 without problems about sounds.

I re install ubuntu 12.04 and update, and also no sound, only by headphones.
Also I tried by Ubuntu Live and doesn't work.

I tried alsamixer, and the sound it's high. and looks like no problem all the configuration, but not are sound by speakers.

Comment: Have the same problem:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/283564/unexpectedly-lost-speaker-output-headphone-output-works-fine

This isn't a Dell laptop bychance?

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided here works for HDA Intel Soundcard. To find the make of your laptop soundcard click here.

**Solution 1:**

Try the following command in the terminal:

```
killall pulseaudio
```

**Solution 2:**

You need to edit this file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and then add a line in its end. Use the following commands:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf &
```

Now add the following line at its end:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

Now reboot your computer. It should solve your problem. If the solution doesn’t work then try the Further Troubleshoot.

Source: http://www.computerandyou.net/2011/06/how-to-solve-no-sound-through-laptop-integrated-speakers-in-ubuntu-11-04/

Comment: no. that's doesn't work. :( Also in the source I tried editing /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf with options snd-hda-intel model=auto and not. It's strange that also in live cd and re installing ubuntu still not working.

Comment: I tried from a live USB of ubuntu 13.04 and also not sound. that's means that is confoguration of sound card maybe?