# Dell Latitude E5440 Sound

Tags: drivers, sound, dell

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Dell Latitude E5440 but i am getting no sound. I've check to ensure that the sound is not muted. Alsamixer tells me it's:

- an `Intel HDA HDMI`
- with and `Intel Haswell HDMI chip`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Now that you have taken the time, and effort might I add, to correct the "grammar" and "readability" of my question, for which I am eternally grateful, would you happen to have a suggestion or perhaps even better a "solution" to my problem? Grammatical perfection was not my intent when I posted the question. Any knowledge that you can share will be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If sound is working via headphones but not via speakers, but you have the drivers, it's probably not working because the sound is outputting to the headphone audio port instead of the speakers. Go into settings and make sure the built in speakers instead of the headphones/port is selected.

If that doesn't help, look here: [Unexpectedly lost speaker output. Headphone output works fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283564/unexpectedly-lost-speaker-output-headphone-output-works-fine)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that sound is not muted. Have a good look at the settings. Make sure the correct sound output is selected.

That Dell is certified by Ubuntu so I'm sure it should work.

Have you tried these drivers?: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/driverdetails?driverid=DRYD9

Comment: I just plugged in my headphones as a test and the sound is working fine via headphones. Just not playing via speakers. I know the speakers work because the machine is dual boot with Windows 7 and the speakers work fine under that OS. I'm just wondering if I missed something along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Install the sound driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```